# PHP regular expression (or function) to convert strings

Tags: php, regex

I would like to be able to convert TV series' episodes from `#7.11` to `S07E11`

For example I have the string `Monk #7.11` or `Family Guy #5.6` 
and I would like to apply a regular expression/function and receive instead `Monk S07E11` or `Family Guy S05E06`.

Comment: you can craft your perfect regex here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: thank you for the link, I'll play with it.

Comment: Consider to find a way of solving a problem you might encounter and include your efforts in the question, rather than just asking for a finished solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, somehow I really didn't know where to start from with this regular expression and I thought I should spare you of my struggles but I'll keep in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$regex="/^([^#]+?) *#([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)$/";
$fmt="%s S%02dE%02d\n";

$items=array(
    "Family Guy #5.6",
    "Monk #7.11",
);

foreach ($items as $one) {
    preg_match($regex, $one, $matches);
    printf($fmt, $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3]);
}
```

Returns:

```
Family Guy S05E06
Monk S07E11
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
function convert($matches) {
  $season = str_pad($matches[1], 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $episode = str_pad($matches[2], 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
  return "S" . $season . "E" . $episode;
}

echo preg_replace_callback("/#(\d+)\.(\d+)/", "convert", "Monk #7.11");
// Monk S07E11  
echo preg_replace_callback("/#(\d+)\.(\d+)/", "convert", "Family Guy #5.6");
// Family Guy S05E06
```

It allows you to provide a function callback that is used to transform the input.

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/JyKzf)**.

Answer (score 1):

PHP Code:

```
$s = 'Monk #7.11';
$p = '/^([^#]+\s)#(\d+)\.(\d+)$/e';
$r = 'sprintf("%sS%02dE%02d", "$1", "$2", "$3")';
echo preg_replace($p, $r, $s);
```

Output:

```
Monk S07E11
```

Test this code [here](http://ideone.com/RwR5i).